# How to close ConnectionPool After executing multiple queries using java, springboot, IBM DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, db2, connection-pooling

Hi I have an application whose connection is always open and increases the count whenever I open/refresh the application in the browser. I am using IBM DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource for connection pool support. The application is running on embedded tomcat server in the springboot project. Any code examples as to how to close the connection pool is appreciated. I have multiple queries executing when I start the server. If I do connection.close(), when the next query is ready to execute it is giving me sqlException as the connection is closed. I want to close the connection after all the queries are executed. Not sure which part of the code I have to do connection.close(). Below is a sample of what I am doing.Thanks in advance.

Example of the code:

```java
@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection con = null;
    DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource pd = null;
    try{
        pd = new DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource();
        pd.setDriverType......
        PooledConnection pc = new PooledConnection();
        con = ((Db2PooledConnection)pc).getDb2Connection(.....);
    catch (Exception e){
    }
    return con;
}
```

If I do connection.close() in finally block after catch, I am getting a sqlException as the connection is closed for the next query to execute.

New Code:

```
@Configuration
   public class DSconfig{
    @Bean
    public DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource poolDS(){
    poolDS.setDriver("testname");
    poolDS.setServerName("test");
    ....
    return poolDS;
  }
}
```

Another Class where I am auto wiring the bean:

```
 public class gettingConnection({
   
@Autowired
private DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource ds;
  @Override
  public Connection getConnection() throws exception{
Connection con = null;
PooledConnection pc = new PooledConnection();
con = (Db2PooledConnection)pc).getDb2Connection(...);
return con;
}
```

When I start my tomcat server it is throwing null pointer exception: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.close()" because "connection" is null

Comment: Seems you are doing the whole process each time you get a connection. The datasource and the pool should be instanciated once and then get connections from the existing pool

Comment: Thank you for the response. Edited the code, does this still seem that the whole process is being done each time. How do I get the connections from the existing pool. Can I set properties like idleTime, poolSize...?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're creating a new data source every time you ask for a connection, rather than asking a single instance of the data source for a connection and let it handle the pooling.

Make the data source a Bean and re-use it.

Comment: Can you please provide any reference or a sample code. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: see: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate

Comment: The idea is that you create the DataSource as a spring @Bean. Then autowire/inject it where you need it.

Comment: Hi, I added the new code above in my question but it is giving me a null connection. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Any suggestions? Am stuck with this from almost 3 weeks. I am using try resource or closing the connection in finally but it is throwing connection null exception.